# Identifying natural an forced response circuits

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis

yesterday my professor introduced us to forced response circuits. I am some what confused on telling the difference when trying to find D.E. for it.

[image: circuit]

**Determine the D.E. governing V(t), t>0.**

This is one of the pratice problems he gave us. Now since t>0 the switch is on B, this means we ignore the 2V and 5omh portion of the circuit.

I found that there is 9V across the capacitor and Tau = 6.

This give me **V(t) = 9e^(-t/6).**

When I looked up a solution(could be wrong) it was **V(t) = 9 - 7e^(-t/6).**

Could someone explain this? Is this because the circuit is a forced response?

Comment: I don't even know what D.E. is. You haven't accounted for the 2V that the cap is initially charged to before t = 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to analyze the current flow of your circuit. You see that the capacitor is loaded by 2 volts and ends up at 9 volts.

Second step is the convert the current supply into a voltage supply; R stays 3 Ohm and the Voltage becomes 9v.
The charging formula of a resistor is:

```
Uc = U(1-e^(-t/τ)
```

While

```
τ = R*C = 3 Ohm * 2 F = 6s
```

The approach I would choose is with a time offset, just add extra time t0 to t, so that when time t is zero, the formula gives 2v

```
2V = 9V(1-e^(-t0/6s)) => t0=1.51s
```

Enter this in the formula:

```
Uc = 9V*(1-e^(-(t+1.51s)/6s))
```

And thats your function at the end. You can simplify this formula by splitting the e';

```
Uc = 9V(1-e^(-t/6s)*e^(-1.51/6))
```

And you end up by this;

```
Uc = 9V - 7V*e^(-t/6s)
```

Comment: Doesn't the left half of the circuit have a different time constant?

Comment: Yes but you assume that it has been precharged by the right side. You just slide the time function until the start point is at 2v. Like f(t)->f(t+a) just a linear translation in t direction.

Comment: Is there another approach besides setting it equal to 2v and solving for t? I don't get a calculator on my exams.

Comment: The 7V could come from the 9V of the source minus the 2V of the precharged capacitor. Deduce with General params, if this law is true, then you don't need a calculator at your exam for the charging function.